# How can I merge more than two lists together in Xamarin forms? I use concat now but that only allows me to add two list into one

Tags: c#

I am using using concat right now to merge lists together but that only allows me to merge two lists together but when I try to merge a third list together it doesnt allow me to do that with my code below.

```
    new List <items> theListOne = new List <items> ();
    new List <items> theListTwo = new List <items> ();
    new List <items> theListThree = new List <items> ();

    var result = theListOne.Concat(theListTwo).ToList();
```

If I want more than two lists together, how would i solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concat as many enumerables as you want

`var result = theListOne.Concat(theListTwo).Concat(theListThree)....ToList();`

Make sure to use ToList() only once at the end to avoid useless enumerations

Comment: Thanks. Works ;) Will give you the answer in 5 mins (cannot accept an answer to soon after i posted it)